# RPC to java based Google App Engine from C# Client

Tags: c#, google-app-engine, xml-rpc

I'm having a lot of problems calling a Java based Google App Engine server from a C# client

This is how my client code looks like:

```
 // C# Client
static void Main(string[] args)
{
  const string URL = "http://localhost:8888/googlewebapptest7/greet";
  HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(URL);
  request.Method = "POST";
  request.ContentType = "text/x-gwt-rpc; charset=utf-8";
  string content = "<?xml version='1.0'?><methodCall><methodName>greetServlet.GetName</methodName><params></params></methodCall>";
  byte[] contentBytes = UTF8Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(content);
  request.ContentLength = contentBytes.Length;
  using (Stream stream = request.GetRequestStream())
  {
    stream.Write(contentBytes, 0, contentBytes.Length);
  }

  // get response
  WebResponse response = request.GetResponse();
  using (Stream responseStream = response.GetResponseStream())
  {
    string res = new StreamReader(responseStream).ReadToEnd();

    Console.WriteLine("response from server:");
    Console.WriteLine(res);
    Console.ReadKey();
  }
```

The server is basically the Google default web project with an additional method:

`public String GetName()
{
   return "HI!";
}`

added to GreetingServiceImpl.

Everytime I run my client, I get the following exception from the server:

`An IncompatibleRemoteServiceException was thrown while processing this call.
com.google.gwt.user.client.rpc.IncompatibleRemoteServiceException: This application is out of date, please click the refresh button on your browser. ( Malformed or old RPC message received - expecting version 5 )`

I would like to keep it in plain HTTP requests.

Any idea what's going on?

Comment: It looks like you're trying to emulate GWT's RPC format. What are you basing this on? What makes you think this particular URL will accept this particular type of RPC call?

Comment: I have overwritten 
protected java.lang.String readContent(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest request)
and can see the incoming call. I thought the XML-RPC request should be enough but when I step though the code, it looks like the request should start with something like 5|?|?|?|? where ? should be integers. I have not investigated what the integers mean yet
Do you have an idea to better approach?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I never found a good way to use XML based RPC on the Google App Engine. Instead i found this excellent JSON library with tutorial:

http://werxltd.com/wp/portfolio/json-rpc/simple-java-json-rpc/

it works very well!

Answer (score 1):

As Nick pointed out you're trying to emulate GWT's RPC format. I tried that too :)

Then I took different approach. I used [Google Protocol Buffers](http://code.google.com/apis/protocolbuffers/) as encoder/decoder over HTTP(S).

One of my projects is desktop application written in C#. Server-side is also C#.Net. Naturally we use [WCF](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/netframework/aa663324) as transport.

You can plug-in Protocol Buffers into WCF transport. You'll have same interface configuration both for C# client and Java server. It's very convenient.

I'll update this answer with code-samples when I'm less busy with work.